# Excel Index Match does mismatch

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm having a problem with Excel 2010 `INDEX`/`MATCH` formulas, and I do not understand why it's happening

I've one Excel Workbook with multiple Worksheets

On the Worksheet named `Routing` there is an entry on line 208 with the value `442890396300`
On the Worksheet `Proposed Routing` on line 116 I have the same value.

When I use the `INDEX`/`MATCH` this way `=INDEX(Routing!$G:$G,MATCH(A116,Routing!A:A))`, it returns a match on line `100`, however the value on line `100` is `442034635973`, what is nowhere near a match.

The entries are numbers and stored as such.

I can provide the spreadsheet but rather would not as it contains proprietary company information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using the third criteria in MATCH:

```
=INDEX(Routing!$G:$G,MATCH(A116,Routing!A:A,0))
```

This forces Match to look for an exact match, otherwise your data must be sorted in ascending order for it to work.

Comment: I should have spotted that myself! Thanks for pointing it out.